# What is 茜 in the phrase 茜纱窗下?

Tags: meaning-in-context

晴雯死了。宝玉祭文。黛玉听见了。宝玉说，”有什么不妥的地方，还请你替我修改修改。“

宝玉写的是：红绡帐里

黛玉说，”何不说 ‘茜纱窗下’“

Is 茜 just 红色? Or is it what the window screen is made of? Is it 芦苇?

Comment: Is this also chapter 79 in your copy?

Comment: No, 三十三。I have a children's copy, the original is too difficult for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*KEY* defines 茜纱 as:

> qiànshā
>   red yarn

So, yes, 茜 = 红 here.

---

David Hawkes English translation in *The Story Of The Stone Volume 3* reads:

> rosy-misted casement

---

Yang Hsien-Yi & Gladys Yang's translation in *A Dream of Red Mansions Vol. 2* reads:

> madder-gauze window

---

It seems as if H. Bencraft Joly never translated this portion of the book.

Comment: 'madder' is not a noun I am familiar with! madder: type of plant (in modern use Rubia tinctorum) yielding a valuable dyestuff, Old English mædere and Old Norse maðra, from PIE *modhro- "dye plant" (source also of Old High German matara "madder," Polish modry, Czech modry "blue").